Terminology for different notions of directional derivatives
I need to discriminate between two versions of directional derivatives of functions between finite-dimensional affine spaces $E$ and $F$:

as the total derivative/differential applied to a fixed vector,

as the derivative of a composition with an affine injection of $\mathbf{R}$.


In the first sense, the directional derivative of $f$ along $v$ is the function $g$ defined by
$$
  g(\boldsymbol{x}) = f'(\boldsymbol{x})(\boldsymbol{v}),
$$
where $f'(\boldsymbol{x})$ is the total derivative/differential of $f$ at $\boldsymbol{x}$. To be clear, by $f'(\boldsymbol{x})$ I mean the linear application $L\colon\vec{E}\to\vec{F}$ such that
$$
  f(\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{h}) - f(\boldsymbol{x}) = L(\boldsymbol{h}) + o(\Vert\boldsymbol{h}\Vert)
$$
as $\boldsymbol{h}\to\boldsymbol{0}_{\vec{E}}$.
In the second sense, the directional derivative of $f$ along $v$ is the function $g$ defined by
$$
  g(\boldsymbol{x}) = (f\circ\gamma)'(0),
$$
where $\gamma\colon\mathbf{R}\to E$ (depending on $\boldsymbol{v}$ and $\boldsymbol{x}$) is defined by
$$
  \gamma(t) =\boldsymbol{x} + t\boldsymbol{v}.
$$
Thus:
$$
  g(\boldsymbol{x}) =\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\boldsymbol{x} + h\boldsymbol{v}) - f(\boldsymbol{x})}{h}.
$$
Of course, directional derivatives in the first sense are restrictions of direction derivatives in the second sense (to the domain of total derivability/differentiability of $f$).
Is there some standard terminology for directional derivatives in the first, stronger, sense? I am thinking about calling them directional derivatives in strong sense (or in total sense?).
I've checked Wikipedia articles about directional derivative, Fréchet derivative, Gateaux derivative and Hadamard derivative, but did not find a specific term for the function $g$ from the first definition. I've seen that some authors use the term directional derivative along $\boldsymbol{v}$ for the function $g$ from the first definition, but more often it is used for the function $g$ from the second definition.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

One last suggestion (in line with Nicholas I believe): there are few more boring terminolgies than "first sense/second sense" . How do you want us to remember what is what? Take the chance and honor Frechet and Gateaux when you invent those terminologies.
